# How to change the favicon in Apache Tomcat 8.x

Tags: tomcat

I have deployed my war file in `Apache Tomcat 8.x` and I want the browser tab icon (i.e. favicon) to be changed.

Currently it is coming as tomcat icon itself. I have tried replacing `apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/ROOT/favicon.ico`, file but it is still not working.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Tomcat itself. This is just standard "favicon" behavior of any web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your own html page add the below line. Add your own png path in the href

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
or
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://eg.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Like in your war you must have a index.html or index.jsp. You can just add above line under `<head>` tag

Comment: and where should I place my favicon.png file?

Comment: you can put it just in the same folder where you have your index.html file.

Comment: It will actually go inside the war once you create the war after coping it in the same forlder where index.html or index.jsp file is present

Comment: It is still not working. I have added my head tag for your reference below :



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" />
</head>



Path of my favicon.png : webapps/UserManagement/favicon.png

Comment: Try to access the fav icon directly from browser. The path will be /UserManagement/favicon.png. The same path you can use in your HTML. Right now the path is wrong

Comment: Tried. Still not working.
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://172.25.184.22:8080/UserManagement/favicon.png"/>

Comment: if you put in browser http://172.25.184.22:8080/UserManagement/favicon.png   does it open the icon ?

Comment: Cool !! Please mark this answer as correct .. if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line in head tag of all of my jsp files :

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost:8080/MYPROJECTFOLDER/favicon.png"/>
```

I placed my favicon.png file in this location :
     **/apache-tomcat-8.X.XX/webapps/MYPROJECTFOLDER/**

Now it is working fine.